# Java Servlets - Make hello world appear on button press

Tags: java, html, servlets

For school we are learning about servlets, and although I understand the idea behind them, I am unsure of how to use them in practice. For a part of a piece of work, we must create a web page in netbeans which contains a button, and when pressed it must invoke a servlet to display the message 'Hello, World!'.

I have my web-page, 'GetHelloMessage.xhtml'

```
<body>
      <div>Click button to show message.</div>
      <p></p>
      <button type="button">Get Message</button>
</body>
```

And 'HelloWorldServlet.java'

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/HelloWorldServlet"})
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>");
    }
}
```

How can I invoke the servlet when the user presses the button?

Comment: Are you using XHTML and not JSP? The `doGet()` method is invoked, when an HTTP GET request is made. In order to display a message, when a button is clicked (which in turn requires a submit button - `<input type="submit" .../>` or else you need to use AJAX), you need to override  the `doPost()` method in the associated Servlet. You can find basic kick off examples in the Servlet tag [Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) itself.

Comment: @Tiny we are not using any JSP only XHTML. I changed my buttons type to submit, but when clicked nothing happens. Do i somehow need to 'link' the servlet to the button? Both files are within the same netbeans project. the xhtml is located within My Project>Web Pages > GetHelloMessage.xhtml and the servlet is located in My Project> Source Packages> default package > HelloWorldServlet.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working i had to edit glassfish-web.xml (located in My Project> WEB-INF) and add the following lines of code:

```
<servlet>
         <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

And in GetHelloMessage.xhtml :

```
<form action="HelloWorldServlet" method="GET">
    <button type="submit">Get Message</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a  tag inside your button tag in order to send the data to your servlet, like this:

```
<body>
  <div>Click button to show message.</div>
  <p></p>
  <button type="button"><a href="helloworldservlet.do">Go to Servlet</a>
  </button>
</body>
```

Note that I am using the .do domain and lowercase, you can use @WebServlet("/helloworldservlet.do") intead of @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/helloworldservlet.do"}).

do like i said and tell me if it works.

Comment: Will that not simply add a hyperlink to the button so that when it is pressed it will open the webpage 'helloworldservlet.do' ?

Comment: Yes, you can use a form tag too, 'cause you are using the doGet method in the servlet. But i think this way should work 'cause you are not sending parameters from your .xhtml file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to invoke the servlet but simply you can go with `a` or `form` tag.

```
<a href='HelloWorldServlet'>Get Message</a>
```

or

```
<form action='HelloWorldServlet'>
  <button>HelloWorldServlet</button>
</form>
```